# How to translate SQL to Relational Algebra on Relational Database Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database, relational-algebra

There are 3 tables: `Students`, `Courses` and `Grades`.

`sid`, `cid` and `sid-cid`(Super key) are the primary keys of each table.

`Students`:

```
sid sname address
-----------------
S1  Adam  Abawama
S2  Mery  Ignora
S3  Aisha Icterra
S4  Sello Icterra
S5  Mery  Kaysers
```

`Courses`:

```
cid cname    dept
------------------
C1  Db       Ceng
C2  Prog     Ceng
C3  Calculus Math
C4  Stat     EE
C5  Alg      Ceng
```

`Grades`:

```
sid cid grade
--------------
S1  C1  50
S1  C2  85
S1  C3  60
S1  C4  90
S1  C5  50
S2  C1  30
S2  C2  40
S3  C2  85
S4  C2  80
S4  C4  75
S4  C5  60
```

Questions

1. List the names of students who taken both a `ceng` and an `EE` course
2. Find the `sid` of student who gets the highest grade from the course `database`

**My SQl Answer for Q1**

```
SELECT s.sname
FROM Students s
JOIN Grades g ON s.sid = g.sid
JOIN Courses c ON g.sid = c.sid
AND c.dept IN ("Ceng","EE")
```

**My SQL Answer for Q2**

```
SELECT sid
FROM Grades
WHERE grade =
    (SELECT max(grade)
     FROM Grades
     GROUP BY cid HAVING Grades.cid = "C1")
```

Answer 1 is returns wrong result, how can fix it? 
how can i write relational algebra for these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design.  You build up the query in stages, validating each stage.  This is a fairly simple query to do — it only needs two steps (though arguably I've compressed two steps into step 2).

#### Step 1

You need to do a self-join in some shape or form.  This query lists students (by `sid`) with a grade in an EE course:

```
SELECT g.sid
  FROM Grades  AS g
  JOIN Courses AS c ON g.cid = c.cid AND c.dept = "EE"
```

#### Step 2

You can use the query in step 1 as one sub-query and the analogous sub-query for "Ceng" to generate two 'tables' with the list of students who do EE and Ceng; you join these tables to come up the students who do both EE and Ceng, and join that with the Students table to list their names:

```
SELECT s.name
  FROM Students AS s
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT g.sid
          FROM Grades  AS g
          JOIN Courses AS c ON g.cid = c.cid AND c.dept = "EE"
       ) AS ee
    ON s.sid = ee.sid
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT g.sid
          FROM Grades  AS g
          JOIN Courses AS c ON g.cid = c.cid AND c.dept = "Ceng"
       ) AS ceng
    ON s.sid = ceng.sid
```

The DISTINCT qualifiers are necessary in case some student takes 2 EE and 1 Ceng course; it prevents them showing up twice in the output.  You could place the DISTINCT in the main query select-list too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

To get some insight you can read "Database System Concepts" or [this](http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/db-book/db6/slide-dir/PPT-dir/ch8.ppt) free slide provided by the writer.

Use this:

```
SELECT s.sname
FROM Students s
JOIN Grades g ON s.sid = g.sid
JOIN Courses c ON g.cid = c.cid
WHERE c.dept = 'Ceng'
INTERSECT 
SELECT s.sid
FROM Students s
JOIN Grades g ON s.sid = g.sid
JOIN Courses c ON g.cid = c.cid
WHERE c.dept = 'EE';
```

Comment: Result must be; S1 and S4, but the result set is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I din't note the "both", ok I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: hoh, may be we can correct write s.sname for s.sid.
SELECT s.sid... Cause we need names :)

Comment: @DjMix - Of course you should, I did this, cause I wanted to show you S1 and S4.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use two correlated subqueries, like so:

```
select S.SNAME
from STUDENTS S
where exists (select G1.SID
              from GRADES G1 inner join COURSES C1 on G1.CID=C1.CID
              where G1.SID = S.SID
                and C1.DEPT = 'Ceng')
  and exists (select G2.SID
              from GRADES G2 inner join COURSES C2 on G2.CID=C2.CID
              where G2.SID = S.SID
                and C2.DEPT = 'EE')
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fd72/4

Comment: additinoally, I got doubled results from My SQL Answer for Q2, Do I have to write DISTINCT key word?

Comment: @DjMix - For Q2, yes, you would need `DISTINCT` since `GRADES` will have the same student ID once for each course.  If the student gets the same grade in every course, you'll see that student's ID come up once for each course!